# Configure ejabberd to use cassandra for mod_mam

Tags: cassandra, erlang, ejabberd

I am having trouble connecting cassandra with ejabberd. Can anyone give me an example configuration file of how to get ejabberd/mod_mam to work with cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd currently does not support Cassandra. At the moment, if you need Cassandra support you need to at that support yourself in ejabberd code.

Comment: Is it possible to add support through ODBC?

Comment: ODBC interface means SQL in ejabberd. I do not think it is the right approach. You probably need to develop native Cassandra integration.